# Is it possible to use diskutil to manipulate the read/write buffer of the SSD portion of the fusion drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, core-storage, fusion-drive

Has anyone been able to use `diskutil` to manipulate the Core Storage LVM into increasing the size of the read/write buffer of the SSD?  Currently the Fusion Drive keeps 4 GB free for new reads/writes.  Is it possible to change this buffer/cache to say 10 GB or 20 GB?

Comment: Appreciate the grammatical corrections but would really appreciate some kind of answer or thoughts regarding this.

Comment: I also very much want to know the answer to this.